# How to drive mapper class through Data

Tags: csvhelper

I am trying to accept a client CSV file, map it to a standard format, and generate a standard output. Except, each client can name the headers differently and ordinal position isn't guaranteed.

I have created the Class for the standard format. I even created a mapper for it that works. I would just like to have the mapper in a database so I can add rows for mappings instead of rebuilding and deploying this code every time a client changes their source file.

```
static void Main()
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader("filepath\\filename.csv"))
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter("filepath\\Output filename.csv"))
            using (var csvIn = new CsvReader(reader))
            {
                csvIn.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<CsvMap>();
                csvIn.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch = (string header, int index) => header.ToUpper();
                var records = csvIn.GetRecords<CsvClass>();
                using (var csvOut = new CsvWriter(writer))
                {
                    csvOut.WriteRecords(records);
                }
            }

        }

public class CsvClass
        {
            [Optional]
            public Guid CompanyID{ get; set; }
            [Optional]
            public string RecordID{ get; set; }
        }
        public sealed class CsvMap : ClassMap<CsvClass>
        {
            public CsvMap()
            {
                Map(m => m.CompanyID).Name("OrganizationID").Optional();
                Map(m => m.CompanyID).Name("CompanyID").Optional();
                Map(m => m.RecordID).Name("RecordID").Optional();
            }
        }
```

I am a database developer and not great with c#, and need a pointer to what I should be using to make it so those mappings can be done through a database or json and have them built out and easily maintable.

```
{"target_field" : "CompanyID"
 "source_field" : "OrganizationID"},
{"target_field" : "CompanyID"
 "source_field" : "CompanyID"},
{"target_field" : "RecordID"
 "source_field" : "RecordID"},
```

thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I use so that I can have my users enter the names of the headings they use and save it for them in a database table.

The `CsvMapping` class stores the header name and the class's property name.

```cs
public class CsvMapping 
{
    public string CsvHeaderName { get; set; }
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
}
```

I then use a helper extension that takes a list of `CsvMapping` and adds them to the `ClassMap`

```cs
public static class CsvHelperExtensions
{
    public static void Map<T>(this ClassMap<T> classMap, IEnumerable<CsvMapping> csvMappings)
    {
        foreach (var mapping in csvMappings)
        {
            var property = typeof(T).GetProperty(mapping.PropertyName);

            if (property == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"Class {typeof(T).Name} does not have a property named {mapping.PropertyName}");
            }

            if (mapping.CsvHeaderName != null)
            {
                classMap.Map(typeof(T), property).Name(mapping.CsvHeaderName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use it like this.

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("OrganizationID,RecordID");
        writer.WriteLine("0CEB1F84-4EA6-4C6D-B758-93BFCDF2B8DE,Record1");
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;

        var mappings = new List<CsvMapping>
        {
            new CsvMapping { CsvHeaderName = "OrganizationID", PropertyName = "CompanyID" },
            new CsvMapping { CsvHeaderName = "RecordID", PropertyName = "RecordID" }
        };

        var csvMap = new CsvMap();

        csvMap.Map(mappings);

        csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap(csvMap);

        var records = csv.GetRecords<CsvClass>().ToList();    
    }
}

public sealed class CsvMap : ClassMap<CsvClass>
{
    public CsvMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.CompanyID).Optional();
        Map(m => m.RecordID).Optional();
    }
}
```